# Not correct show filter by date delta

Tags: postgresql-9.5

**created_at** column type is timestamp with timezone.

Current date time is **17 Sep 2020 12:52:34**

My time is GMT+3

I want to show all created_at < 1 hour (3600 sec)

Query:

```
 SELECT id, created_at from mytable
 WHERE (extract(epoch from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - created_at)::integer < 3600)
 order by created_at desc
```

But here result:
[image]

As you can see records has **created_at** more than 3600 sec.

Why?

I try `'1 hours'` but it also not help.
It show records **> 1 hour**

[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not help. Same result

Comment: Why the conversion to seconds at all? `where current_timestamp - created_at < interval '1 hour'`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is example (1 hour). It's maybe 400 sec, 10 sec and so on

Comment: Then use the appropriate values for that: `interval '400 seconds'` or `interval '2 days'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not help. Same result: WHERE  current_timestamp - created_at < interval '3600 seconds'

Comment: Well for the sample data shown, the difference between `2020-09-17 12:52:34` ("current timestamp")  and the column's values is all **bigger** then 1 hour, so it's no surprise a condition that says `< 1 hour` doesn't return any rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's return many records. This is the problem

Comment: You need to create a self-contained example, because with the data you have shown us, that query does not return anything: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4e8ba481d106b086e3a9dd87f0b3e31e

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was updated my post